# How to Get Top N Values for Each Group, with Counts in a list Using Window Functions in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm working on a PySpark project and I'm facing an issue with extracting the top N values for each group in a DataFrame using window functions. I have a DataFrame with three columns: **variation, name, and count**. The variation column contains variations of some merchants, the name column contains  names, and the count column indicates the count of items for each variation-name combination.

What I want to achieve is to extract the top N names for each variation based on their counts. I'm using the rank function to assign ranks to names within each variation group, and then filtering for the rows with a rank of N.

Here's the code I've tried so far:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# Initializing Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("TopNames").getOrCreate()

# Reading the DataFrame
df = spark.read.csv("my_data.csv", header=True)

# Defining a window specification
window_spec = Window.partitionBy("variation").orderBy(F.desc("count"))

# Adding rank and row_number columns
df_ranked = df.withColumn("rank", F.rank().over(window_spec)).filter("rank<=10")
result_df = df_ranked.groupBy('variation').agg(
    F.struct(
        F.first('name').alias('top_name'),
        F.first('count').alias('top_count')
    ).alias('top_name_count')
)
# Filtering for the top N names
```

However, I'm getting multiple rows for the same variation due to the presence of duplicate ranks, and the top_name list has different sizes in each rows. I only need one row per variation with the longest list of names. How can I achieve this?

How can I properly extract the top N merchants for each variation using PySpark's window functions?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new column called `name_length`, then add that column to the partition and order by descending `count` and `name_length` to create the `rank` column. This allows us to use the longest name to break ties between duplicate `counts` within the same `variation` to create `df_ranked`.

For example:

```
pandas_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'variation': ['a']*6+['b']*6+['c']*6,
    'name': ['ab','abc','abcd','abcdef','aa','bb']*3,
    'count': [6,6,6,6,5,5,1,5,4,4,3,3,3,3,2,2,1,1],
})

df = spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df)

# Defining a window specification
window_spec = Window.partitionBy("variation").orderBy(F.desc("count"),F.desc("name_length"))

# Adding rank and row_number columns
df_ranked = df.withColumn(
    "name_length", F.length("name")
).withColumn(
    "rank", F.rank().over(window_spec)
).filter(
    "rank<=3"
)
```

This gives us `df_ranked`:

```
+---------+------+-----+-----------+----+
|variation|  name|count|name_length|rank|
+---------+------+-----+-----------+----+
|        a|abcdef|    6|          6|   1|
|        a|  abcd|    6|          4|   2|
|        a|   abc|    6|          3|   3|
|        b|   abc|    5|          3|   1|
|        b|abcdef|    4|          6|   2|
|        b|  abcd|    4|          4|   3|
|        c|   abc|    3|          3|   1|
|        c|    ab|    3|          2|   2|
|        c|abcdef|    2|          6|   3|
+---------+------+-----+-----------+----+
```

And then when we create `result_df`, we get the expected result:

```
result_df = df_ranked.groupBy('variation').agg(
    F.struct(
        F.first('name').alias('top_name'),
        F.first('count').alias('top_count')
    ).alias('top_name_count')
)

+---------+--------------+
|variation|top_name_count|
+---------+--------------+
|        a|   {abcdef, 6}|
|        b|      {abc, 5}|
|        c|      {abc, 3}|
+---------+--------------+
```

Comment: did this end up helping?